# How to open this lantern sconce?

Tags: light-fixture

Nothing is removable at the top, and it does not have external fasteners. The bottom bezel unscrews but the globe or housing won’t drop out. Cannot believe I can’t figure it out...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found. I found some screws on the top, and photos added to the original post and here.[image]

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be a gap between two components. The top and the cage may be screwed together.

[image]

Comment: This is wrong, as proved by the OP’s follow-up. Please delete it.